# popup with effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var popup;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
 jQuery(window).bind('load',windowLoadComplete);  
});

function windowLoadComplete() {
  var settings = new Object();
  popup = new SSKpopup(settings);
  popup.createPopup();

  jQuery('a').each(function(n){
    if(jQuery(this).attr('href').indexOf("popup@")>-1) {
       jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href').split("popup@")[1]).hide();
       jQuery(this).click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         popup.loadContent(jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href').split("popup@")[1]));
        });

    }                           
  });
}
```

I have that piece of code that is to create a popup containing pictures, information just like like http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ and in my html code I create the popup as follows,

```
<a class="popup" href="/main/popup@#hulk">Key Speakers</a>
<br>
Chairman
</p>
<div id="hulk" style="width: 450px; display: none;">
<img class="popup_img" border="0" alt="" src="/main/images/speaker.jpg">
<p>Content descriping the speakers</p
</div>
```

When I use firebug over the href I see the address different from normal location and if I insert into its as `index.php/main/popup@$hulk` to be same as every other links and click it then, the page direct me to `localhost/xampp/`. Of course no popup was displayed.

Comment: try to give a new location to the a tag maybe the path you gave is wrong

Comment: Can you post the source/documentation to SSKpopup? It's rather hard to debug a piece of code we can't see.

Comment: Thank you I really wanted to, but company doesnot allow employees to disclose credential information to the outside :-(

Comment: Sorry, but without code or a replication of your issue (using something like http://jsfiddle.net) there is next-to-nothing anybody here is going to be able to do for you.